# Disable default browser behaviour for html5 contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, froala

Hi either using css or Javascript I wish to prevent all browsers default behaviour of the html5 contenteditable attribute so it does not allow (inline) editing of the HTML contained within its section...
 So when I have a section like this:

```html
<div class="carouselitembox col-sm-5" contenteditable="true">
     <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum reiciendis!</h3>
     <p style="padding-right: 5px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Eos repellendus molestias minus aperiam quaerat ipsam sunt commodi distinctio eum perspiciatis.</p>
  <a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find out more</a>
</div>
```

For anouther example see: https://jsfiddle.net/angusgrant/23c5gnz4/36/ also giving an indication of usage and reason i need this.

Comment: So what behaviour would you like to see instead? The answer is a no, though. You cannot amend/override the default `contenteditable` behaviour. If you want different behaviour for an editable field you'll need to create it yourself.

Comment: I just wish it to treat it as if the attribute was set false or not set at all.

Comment: So you want to edit the content using `contenteditable`, but have `contenteditable="false"`...? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You say _"So when I have a section like this:"_ ... then what? It is not very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: So Froala the WYSIWYG editor uses the contenteditable attribute to determine which parts of the html are editable and which are not I want to retain this behaviour but lose the inline browser edit behaviour that allows you to make changes in the browser by clicking /selecting a element that has this attribute with your cursor.